# Overlap home button using Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm using the (relatively) new Toolbar widget instead of an ActionBar. I'm trying to overlap the home menu button (burger) with a notification icon.

I've tried a few hacky things to get this done but nothing has worked.

Has anyone faced a similar situation?

Thanks!

Comment: I would try something like this: https://gist.github.com/r0adkll/6e66744f6477aaf48375 in place of where you put your Toolbar widget.

Comment: So simple, yet it works! Please write this as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From comment:**

Since the new Toolbar is just a view widget you can position other views above it in your layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        ....
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notif_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="6dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/....."

        android:layout_marginLeft="..dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="..dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then just position the `notif_icon` with the layout_margin left and top values to get it into the position that you want above the hamburger icon.

It is also important to note that the ImageView, or whatever view your using in this usecase, have the same `android:elevation` value or greater or else it won't draw above the app bar.